# PhoneGap for mobile and Appcelerator for desktop+mobile?

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova, appcelerator

It seems that PhoneGap is only for mobil devices while Appcelerator is for desktop and the mobile, am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes Appcelerator can be used for both

http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-cross-platform-application-development/

have not actually used it but did some investigation

Comment: Then the question if I can create desktop apps with PhoneGap. It seems to not be the case.

Comment: There are seeds of a desktop version, but limited: http://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mac